# Check if item in string exist in array TS

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, firebase

I have the following string

"0,2,4,5,6"

how can check if these numbers are in array

```
let daysweek = [
    { id: '0', name: 'Domingo' },
    { id: '1', name: 'Segunda' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Terça' },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank you all, I found a example that met my need

```
daysweek2 = [
     'Domingo',
     'Segunda',
     'Terça',
     'Quarta',
     'Quinta',
     'Sexta',
     'Sábado',
];


function initDays() {
   return "0,2,4".split(',')
      .map(key => this.daysweek2[key]).join(',').split(',')
}


console.log(this.initDays());
```

Comment: This doesn't address the problem in the Question at all

Answer (score 2):

Create a set of the ids in `daysofweek`, allowing you to easily check if an id is in `daysweek`.

```js
let daysweek = [
   { id: '0', name: 'Domingo' },
   { id: '1', name: 'Segunda' },
   { id: '2', name: 'Terça'   },
];

let days = "0,2,4,5,6";

let set = new Set(daysweek.map( _ => _.id ))
let found_days = days.split(",").filter( day => set.has(day) );

console.log(found_days);
```

This is O(N). AlwaysHelping's answer and MarkCBall's answers are O(N<sup>2</sup>), which will fare far more poorly as the number of items in `daysweek` increases.

Comment: Oh well! looks like the OP did not care about any of our solutions and brought his own different question and solution to it - `O(N^2)` and `O(1)` etc etc makes no point here now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to do that.

`Split()` will remove all `commas` from your `string` and convert it an `array`.

And using `map` we get all the id's with and store them in a `variable` and check using [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which id's matched with `string` you have.

**Live Demo:**

```js
let daysweek = [{
    id: '0',
    name: 'Domingo'
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Segunda'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Terça'
  },
];

let str = "0,2,4,5,6".split(',') //split the string
let  daysID = daysweek.map(y => y.id) //store the id's
str.forEach(function(x){    
    let found = daysID.includes(x)
    console.log(x + " = " +found) //show true or false for each found id
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let daysweek = [
    { id: '0', name: 'Domingo' },
    { id: '1', name: 'Segunda' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Terça' },
];
const daysWeekIds = daysweek.map(obj=>obj.id)

const numbersAreInArray = "0,2,4,5,6".split(",").every(num=>daysWeekIds.includes(num))
console.log(numbersAreInArray)
```